# NoMethod Error - Controller Actions fail to work randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

The bookings controller looks like:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @bookings = @event.bookings.all
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.create(booking_params)
    @booking.ticket = @ticket

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
    #token = params[:stripeToken]
    @amount = @booking.total_amount

    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => @booking.email,
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
        )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount,
        :currency => "usd",
        #:card => token
        )
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for the order"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
    end  
    if @booking.save
        BookingMailer.booking_confirmation_user(@booking).deliver
        redirect_to [@event, @booking]
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    redirect_to event_bookings_path
  end

  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:buyer_name, :email, :mobile, :address, :order_quantity, :ticket_id)
  end
end
```

The booking model:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  #before_create :check_ticket_count

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :ticket
  has_many :charges

  def total_amount
    ticket.ticket_price.to_i * order_quantity.to_i
  end

  def check_ticket_count
    count = ticket.ticket_quantity.to_i - order_quantity.to_i
    ticket.update_attribute(:ticket_quantity, count)
  end

end
```

Ticket model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :check_start_date
  before_update :check_start_date


    def check_start_date
        if (self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now) && (self.booking_end_date != DateTime.now)
            self.status = 'Open'
        else
            self.status = 'Closed'
        end
    end

    def maximum_tickets_allowed
        (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
    end

end
```

The Bookings Index Page:

```
<h2>All Bookings</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Buyer Name</th>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                  <th>Ticket Type</th>
                  <th>No. of Tickets</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @event.bookings.each do |booking| %> 
              <tr> 
                  <td><%= booking.buyer_name %></td>
                  <td><%= booking.email %></td>
                  <td><%= booking.ticket.ticket_name %></td>
                  <td><%= booking.order_quantity %></td>
                  <td><%= number_to_currency(booking.total_amount) %></td>                  
                  <td><%= link_to "Delete", event_booking_path(@event, booking), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Bookings show page:

**Thanks for your purchase!**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <b>Name:</b><p><%= @booking.buyer_name %></p>
        <b>No. of Tickets</b><p><%= @booking.order_quantity %></p>
        <b>Ticket Tier</b><p><%= @booking.ticket.ticket_name %></p>
        <b>Amount Paid:</b><p><%= number_to_currency(@booking.total_amount) %></p>
        <p><% @booking.check_ticket_count %></p>
    </div>
```

Now, my problem is bookings work perfectly. All the details are fetched, displayed and model methods executed properly. However, occasionally without even making one single change to these files, I get the "Action controller exception caught error - NoMethodError in Bookings#index" and "Action controller exception caught error - NoMethodError in Bookings#show". The culprit is always the ticket_name in booking.ticket.ticket_name and @booking.ticket.ticket_name where the error states that it's an undefined method.

Full trace is here:

```
app/views/bookings/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_bookings_index_html_erb___3226472832114682596_70125337010980'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
app/views/bookings/index.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_bookings_index_html_erb___3226472832114682596_70125337010980'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

The problem is it's the right field name. Why would the actions work most of the times and fail randomly at times without a single change in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

booking.ticket is probably blank

You can do

```
<td><%= booking.ticket.ticket_name rescue nil %></td>
```

or

```
<td>
  <% unless booking.ticket.blank? %>
    <%= booking.ticket.ticket_name %>
  <% else %>
    No Ticket
</td>
```

Comment: how could the ticket_name value be blank? The names are fetched from the DB tables and they aren't empty. And, the buy now button is listed right next to ticket name in the events show page.

Comment: ticket_name value is not the blank. It is the booking.ticket.   Basically it is not finding a ticket associated with that booking so it is nil therefore it doesnt have the method ticket_name.

Comment: Now, I'm getting the ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `ticket_price' for nil:NilClass) error in the line <td><%= number_to_currency(booking.total_amount) %></td>. The total_amount model method uses ticket_price to calculate the total value of the booking.